# Согласование причастий

Tags: согласование

"Спешивших" или "спешащих", "горевшими" или "горящими" надо использовать в данном предложении: "Дома защищались, зажигая последние окна и неоновую рекламу на крышах, призывали на помощь фары машин, спешивших довезти своих владельцев до уютных кресел перед горевшими каминами"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В русском языке на этот счет нет строгих грамматических правил, поэтому можно говорить только о стилистической предпочтительности выбора. Хотя иногда такой выбор предопределяет и смысл, но это надо на конкретных примерах разбирать.

> "горевшими" или "горящими"

**Горящими**. Здесь нужно настоящее время, поскольку действие (пусть и неназванное) предполагает согласование моментов появления "владельцев" перед каминами и горения этих каминов.

> "Спешивших" или "спешащих"

А вот тут сложнее. Я бы тоже предпочел настоящее время (**спешащих**), но но это уже очень тонкий момент.  Попробую изложить.

В современном русском языке в отношении причастий (и даже в большей степени - деепричастий) для согласования используется не абсолютная привязка по времени: в прошлом, настоящем и ли будущем, происходит действие, выраженное причастием, а относительная: до или во время (много реже - после) основного действия это происходит.  Но это, как сказал, тенденция, а не императивное правило. 
Поэтому, если основное действие выражено глаголом в прошедшем времени, выбор грамматического времени причастия несовершенного вида фактически не сказывается на смысле. Если бы это правило было предписано грамматикой, а не стилистикой, то смысл конструкций *"фары машин, спешащих довезти"* и *"фары машин, спешивших довезти"*  был бы разным. В первом случае имелось бы в виду, что машины спешили в момент, указанный основным действием (когда "дома защищались"), а во втором - до этого, то есть в прошлом не только по **отношению к моменту повествования**, по отношению **к моменту действия повествования**. Это то, что в грамматике обычно понимается под давнопрошедшим временем. Но в русской грамматике давнопрошедшее время давным-давно утеряно, причем задолго до того, как сформировалась современная грамматика причастий. И едва ли носители языка прочувствуют разницу в употреблении.

Поэтому можно говорить лишь об очень тонкой стилистической разнице, которая дает небольшое преимущество варианту настоящего времени причастия.

*Я не искал ссылок, подтвеждающих мое видение ситуации. Просто потому, что в конечном-то счете пришел к выводу, что все это не слишком актуально для практики.*

Answer (score 2):

Роли не играет. Для сохранения единообразия времени логично писать "спешивших". Но "спешащих" позволяет "сфокусироваться на моменте", как бы воспроизвести его. Это чисто художественная разница. В приведённом Вами контексте она не влияет на смысл текста. Можно и так и этак.